# Задание на TableView, удаление ячеек

Tags: массивы, ios, uitableview

Есть TableView состоящий из двух секции. Каждая из секций заполняется из одного из двух массивов.

Задача состоит в том чтобы при нажатии удаления ячейки(например №2) во второй секции, ячейка удалилась в первой - тоже под №2, ну и в обратном порядке, чтобы тоже работало

```
  #import "ViewController.h"


CGFloat tableViewHeaderHeigth = 50;
CGFloat tableViewFooterHeight = 50;

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *firstArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *secondArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
     self.secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", @"4", @"5", nil];

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
     self.tableView = tableView;
    }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView //кол-ва секций
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) {
        return self.firstArray.count;
    } else if (section==1) {
        return self.secondArray.count;
    }

    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSString *reUseId = @"Cell";

    //Поиск ячейки
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reUseId];

    if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:reUseId];
    }
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        cell.textLabel.text = [self.firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    button.frame = cell.frame;
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(didPressDeleteButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell addSubview:button];


    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return YES;
}


-(void)didPressDeleteButton:(id)sender{

    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        if (indexPath.section == 0){
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = self.firstArray.mutableCopy;
        [tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.firstArray = tempArray.mutableCopy;
        }

    else {
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = self.secondArray.mutableCopy;
        [tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.secondArray = tempArray.mutableCopy;


    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**Обновление**

Наглядный пример. Если нажать ужалить пятую ячейку, то удалиться должна 5 ячейка из нижней секции

[image: img]

Comment: Вы код сами писали или не понимаете что там происходит?

Уберите *if (indexPath.section == 0){* *}else{* и будет Вам счастье

Comment: писал сам, не понимаю как с из массива удалить такой же индекс как и в другом

Comment: `[tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`- а эта строка что делает?

Comment: это строка понятно что делает - удаляет из массива,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меня вопрос поставил в тупик. Все уже написано в коде и непонятно, что вызвало сложности. Два идентичных массива, один и тот же индекс.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // это индекс, элемент которого нужно удалить из обоих массивов
        int index = indexPath.row;

        // создаем изменяемую копию первого массива
        NSMutableArray *tempArray1 = self.firstArray.mutableCopy;

        // удаляем элемент находящийся по индексу
        [tempArray1 removeObjectAtIndex: index];

        // заменяем первый массив на новый
        self.firstArray = tempArray1.mutableCopy;

        // создаем изменяемую копию второго массива
        NSMutableArray *tempArray2 = self.secondArray.mutableCopy;

        // удаляем элемент находящийся по индексу. Индекс тот же что и в первом массиве
        [tempArray2 removeObjectAtIndex: index];

        // заменяем второй массив на новый
        self.secondArray = tempArray2.mutableCopy;

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало!